# Rails Scope: Select Distinct Title With Values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord, rails-postgresql

I'm having trouble with an SQL query in a scope. I need to return a collection of unique Project.titles and their accompanying ids for use in a form.

I can get the distinct title using

```
scope :unique_title, select("DISTINCT title")
```

But I don't get the value in the resulting options

`= project_form.input :id, collection: current_user.projects.unique_title`

Result:

```
<select>
  <option value>Item 1</option>
  <option value>Item 2</option>
  <option value>Item 3</option>
</select>
```

So, adding id to my scope:

```
scope :unique_title, select("DISTINCT title").select("id")
```

Result gives me the values but now my DISTINCT selection is defunct:

```
<select>
  <option value="1">Item 1</option>
  <option value="2">Item 2</option>
  <option value="3">Item 3</option>
  <option value="4">Item 2</option>
  <option value="5">Item 2</option>
  <option value="6">Item 2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: How do you want the ids of the different grouped titles? only the id of the first match or all the ids with that title?

Comment: I want the id relating to each title to be in the html value eg `<option value="1">Item 1</option>`. That way I can find the selected option in the controller once the form is submitted.

Comment: So the best approach would be to use PARTITION BY

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you will not be able to select another field along with a `Distinct` select retaining its distinctiveness.

I think you might be looking for `GROUP BY` which can be used like this in Rails:

```
scope :unique_title, select("id, title").group("title")
```

But, this will select only the first from the group which have the same title. If you want all the records but need to group them according to their title, you will need to fetch all records and afterwards group them from Ruby.

```
scope :titles, select("id, title")
```

then where you use the scope, you sh:

```
Model.titles.all.group_by(&:title).each do |distinct_title, records|
  # do something with the distinct title and records having that distinct title
end
```

Comment: I was afraid of that. So I've got these in a form as a collection_select. Will the block you've suggested work nested in a select_tag? IE I've got no clue!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done SQL il a while, so this might not do it, but I'd go with `.select("id, title DISTINCT)`

PS : If you're using Rails 3.2, you can use `explain` to see what query is actually used (at least I *think* you can, haven't tried it yet), and why it doesn't work as you expect.

Comment: Thanks, I did try the `.select("id, title DISTINCT")` query and got the following error `PGError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "DISTINCT" LINE 1: SELECT id, title DISTINCT FROM "workouts"  WHERE "workouts".`

Answer (score 0):

I've taken a different approach to solve this.

A new column on my Project model

```
$ rails g migration add_template_to_project template:boolean
```

Added to the model

```
before_create :check_if_exists

def check_if_exists
  toggle!(:template) if title.exists?
end
```

Then the scope can be:

```
scope :unique_title, select("id, title").where(template: true)
```

Works a charm

Comment: That's a lot of overhead. You should rubyprince's way. It will give you what you want, you sais "unique Project.titles" and that `group by` will do just that. It won't give you repeated titles with different IDs but you don't want that. It's a lot faster and cleaner than the above solution. Cheers.

Comment: doesn't work as you will get "column .id\" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function